# linux ftp entire directory recursively

Tags: linux

hi i am using ftp command from linux to try to download a site from another server. i can log in fine but when i try to download the entire site with mget * 
i get osmething like this

```
local: email/: No such file or directory
local: includes/: No such file or directory
```

i think it's saying i dont have that directory on my destination server. but i am admin i have access to create folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the basic `ftp` client's `mget` will create directories for you.  `ncftp` is a client that supports what you're looking for.  You might check the [FTP mini-HOWTO](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/FTP.html) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) .    Version 3.22-3 is the best, if you can find it, cuz it has no ad-ware on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different FTP client.  I don't know what distro you're using but under Kubuntu there is kasablanca and with that you can select to transfer an entire directory.  There are other options but you may have more luck with those.

Answer (score 0):

The "wget" utility has a --mirror option you can use.  I've used it a lot for archiving sites, and it does the job well enough.